# YII2 jQuery select2 functions error when renderAjax

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2

I have a page, where I view a form.

**viewpage.php**

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use app\models\AutoMakes;

$this->title = 'Ваше новое объявление';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

$form = ActiveForm::begin([
                      'options' => [
                        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                        'name' => 'parts'
                      ],
                    ]); ?>

              <?= $form->field($model, 'make[]', ['options' => ['class' => 'makesselect']])
                          ->label('')
                          ->widget(Select2::classname(),
                            [
                              'data' => AutoMakes::getMakesSelectList(),
                              'language' => 'ru',
                              'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Марка автомобиля', 'class' => 'makesselect'],
                              'pluginOptions' => [
                                'allowClear' => true
                              ]
                            ]) ?>
            <?= $form->field($model, 'model[]', ['options' => ['class' => '']])
                        ->label('')
                        ->widget(Select2::classname(),
                          [
                            'data' => [],
                            'language' => 'ru',
                            'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Модель','class' => 'modelsselect'],
                            'pluginOptions' => [
                              'allowClear' => true
                            ]
                          ]) ?>
      <?php ActiveForm::end();
```

By jQuery "change" function I loading the same form from SiteController with renderAjax.

**SiteController.php**

```
    public function actionAjaxAction()
    {
      if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
              $model = new AddAdvert();
              $cities = Cities::getCities();

              $citiesArr = array();
              foreach ($cities as $city) {
                $citiesArr[$city->city_id] = $city->name;
              }

              asort($citiesArr);

              $response = '';
              $model->category_id = (int)$actionData['actionData']['type'];
              return $this->renderAjax('add', ['model' => $model, 'cities' => $citiesArr]);
}
}
```

When form from ajax loaded, select2 elements stop working (change function must change other select):

```
$('body').on('change','#addadvert-make,#adverts-make',function(){
    var data = {};
    data.make = $(this).val();
    sendAction(data,'getModelsList');
});
```

But on first page loading they works.

Comment: maybe because youre using id `#addadvert-make,#adverts-make` as the element selector, id is unique to each element. try using class instead. And im guessing that the form above is not the one rendered since `add` view is being renderajax?

Comment: I tried to change `change` function to `$('body').on('change','select.makesselect',function(){}`. There is work like need on page loading, but no reaction after renderAjax

Comment: I found, that with renderAjax all scripts adds to view one more time. I think, this adding cause conflict. But when I tried to use renderPartial, the select2 fields not initiated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in duplicate JS-files, loading with `renderAjax` function.

I changed function to `renderPartial` and render response to form div block. After this I reinit Select2 widget with:

```
$('.site-add-advert select.makesselect,.site-add-advert select.modelsselect, .site-add-advert .field-addadvert-city select').select2({
    theme:'krajee-bs4',
});
$('.kv-plugin-loading').remove();
```

and it is all good!